# passing list of arguments to another function when one argument is a vector

Tags: r

I'll try to explain this with an example: I want to minimize a function `f1` with a function like `nlm`, and at the same time I want to pass some arguments to `nlm` from a list of arguments.

In the easy case, both these work and minimize the function

```
f1 <- function(x, vec) x^2 +sum(vec)
nlm(f = f1, p = 0.2, vec = 1)
nlm(f = f1, p = 0.2, vec = c(1,1))
```

Then if I want to have a list `opt_pars` to be passed to `nlm`, I would usually do this

```
opt_pars <- list(hessian = TRUE)
do.call(what = nlm, args = c(f = f1, p = 0.2, vec = 1, opt_pars))
```

However, the problem is that this does not work if `vec` is actually a vector:

```
do.call(what = nlm, args = c(f = f1, p = 0.2, vec = c(1,1), opt_pars))
```

It seems to me that this happens because `c()` splits `vec` into two vectors:

```
> str(c(f = f1, p = 0.2, vec = c(1,1), opt_pars, recursive= TRUE))
List of 5
 $ f      :function (x, vec)  
  ..- attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 1 7 1 36 7 36 1 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x113e377c0> 
 $ p      : num 0.2
 $ vec1   : num 1
 $ vec2   : num 1
 $ hessian: logi TRUE
```

What would be a good way of dealing with this?

Comment: All elements of an atomic vector in R has to be of the same type. So `c` coerces all elements to the same type. What you want is `list`, which allows different element types. See `?do.call`, it takes a `list` as the second argument.

Comment: this should work: `do.call(nlm, args = c(list(f = f1, p = 0.2, vec = c(1,1)), opt_pars))`

Comment: thanks Adam, that works. If you put your comment as an answer then I can close the question